# Laravel 5.2: Different view-layout depending on route

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I'd like to have two routes for every page on my website.

One route should extend the view from `layouts/foo.blade.php` and the other route should extend from `layouts/bar.blade.php`.

For example if enter `example.com/foo/about` I get my about-page with foo-layout. If I enter `example.com/bar/about` I get my about-page with bar-layout.

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use [Request::segment()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_segment) (or something like this), in order to dynamically set your base layout:

```
@extends( Request::segment(1) == 'foo' ? 'foo.blade.php' : 'bar.blade.php')
```

Where `1` (segment argument) is the first URL segment.

Comment: Thanks @felipsmartins, works great. Though I was hoping for a solution where I didn't have to add this line to every template.

Comment: Also, I think it should be `@extends( Request::segment(1) == 'foo' ? 'layouts.foo' : 'layouts.bar')`